# can `operator<` of some type have different definitions between compilation units?

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

I wanted to create a `std::set<X>`, for a pod struct, `X`.
I tried providing a free `operator<`.
I did not want this operator to have a global effect (outside this compilation unit),
so I set the `operator<` as **static**.  ([link to code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41def2acb8aaf081))

```
struct X { int value; };

static bool operator< (const X& a, const X& b) { return a.value < b.value; }

void foo() {
    std::set<X> some_set;
    some_set.insert({1});
}
```

This compiles fine.

However, if I move the `operator<` in an **unnamed namespace** ([link to code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84c2fa57f5088a02))

```
struct X { int value; };
namespace {
     bool operator< (const X& a, const X& b) { return a.value < b.value; }
}

void foo() {
    std::set<X> some_set;
    some_set.insert({1});
}
```

which should be equivalent,

then `std::less<X>` complains:

```
usr/local/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_function.h:408:20: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const X' and 'const X')
         { return __x < __y; }
```

Okay, I could have used a custom comparator instead.

But can anybody explain why the above does not work?
In general, is it possible to provide a different operator implementation in compilation units of the same struct?

Comment: This would violate One Definition Rule and lead to Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @MarekR Not with `static` functions.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat note there is `std::less` involved when using `std:set`, this example is quirky and interesting. I do not know what will happen if only `static` version is used (IMO UB), but version with anonymous namespace can do not compile and this can be nicely explained.

Comment: Read about one definition rule

Comment: @Ronald, one definition rule has to do with global symbols. But I am clearly trying to to break this by setting the operators as static, or in an unnamed namespace. How do you suggest I am violating the ODR ?

Answer (score 4):

This boils down to following:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};

namespace
{
    void foo(A) {} // Your `operator<`.
}

namespace N
{
    void foo(int) {} // Some random `operator<` in `std`.

    template <typename T>
    void bar(T value)
    {
        foo(value);
    }
}

int main()
{
    N::bar(A{});
}
```

This doesn't work because `N::foo` shadows `foo(A)` in the unnamed namespace.

If there was no unnamed namespace, `foo(A)` would instead be found via [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), because it would be in the same namespace as `A`.

---

Also note that this appears to violate one-definition rule. While your `operator<` is `static`, `std::less` is not, and its instantiations in different translation units will pick different `operator<`s, which appears to be illegal.

This could cause one of our `operator<`s to be used in every TU, when inline implementations of `std::less` from different TUs are ultimately merged by the linker.

Comment: what you are saying implies that even if I create 2 files, each with a (different) `namespace {struct Comparator}`,  to sort a different `set<X, Comparator>` variable, then we get an ODR vialation via `std::less`?
I am pretty sure I've seen the exported symbols of the .obj files (using `nm`) containing class template instantiantions of classes in unnamed namespaces, and:
- if the templated classes (eg `set<int, Comparator>`) contain instantiations of local classes (eg. `namespace{ struct Comparator}`) then they don't enter the symbolic table at also!

Comment: @GrimFandango If you specify a custom comparator, then `less` is not called (being the *default* comparator), so you're fine. This ODR violation only happens if you overload `operator<` differently in different files.